# Thymeleaf - cannot get a value from hashmap sent in as context

Tags: thymeleaf

I have been trying to generate html code with thymeleaf through recursion. In order to do this I need to be able to define a fragment that I can let call itself. The logic here requires however access to objects that are set in the context:

```java
        HashMap<String, Object> values = new HashMap<>();
        values.put("components", components.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(OrderComponent::getId, Function.identity())));

        Document document = new Document(documentTemplate);
        document.setCreationDate(new Date());
        document.setOrder(order);

        Context ctx = new Context();
        ctx.setVariables(values);
        document.setContent(templateEngine.process(documentTemplate.getContent(),ctx));
```

I have been able to access these objects in the template already successfully. However, I also need to be able to get them in the fragment:

```html
<div class="compDetail" th:each="cabComp : ${compService.filterComponentsByType(topLevelComponent.getComponents(), new String('CabinetComponent'))}">
....
                <th:block th:fragment="fragment_cmp(cmpId)">
                    <div class="compBody-ItemDesc-Indent-textbox">
                        [[${cmpId}]]
                        [[${components.get(cmpId).getName()}]]
                    </div>
                </th:block>
                <th:block th:replace="::fragment_cmp(cmpId = ${cabComp.getId()})"/>
....
</div>
```

I get the following error message on execution:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: target is null for method getName
    at ognl.OgnlRuntime.callMethod(OgnlRuntime.java:1613) ~[ognl-3.1.12.jar:na]
    at ognl.ASTMethod.getValueBody(ASTMethod.java:91) ~[ognl-3.1.12.jar:na]
```

Still, when I try to evaluate the existence of the components variable, it seems to be there. Calling its size() method returns me nicely the size of the hashmap.... Same goes for the cmpId variable. But using both together to get a value out of the hashmap does not work :(. I am sure that the component exists in the hashmap for the given id.

I am using thymeleaf in a spring boot context, but I am using it only as a templating engine to generate HTML to be transformed into PDF. So, I imported

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.11.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

**Update**
After some more experimenting I have found out that this must be some sort of pre-processing issue. When I trace the call being made to a method in the service I am passing, it seems that id is set to 0:

[image]

The thymeleaf fragment looked like this when doing the test:

```html
                <div th:fragment="fragment_cmp(cmpId)">
                    <div class="compBody-ItemDesc-Indent-textbox" th:with="component=${components.get(cmpId)}">
                        <span th:text="${cmpId}"/>
                        <span th:text="${compService.get(cmpId).getName()}"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <th:block th:replace="::fragment_cmp(cmpId = ${cabComp.getId()})"/></th:block>
```

Comment: For `${cabComp.getId()}`, how is `cabComp` evaluated? It does not appear to be added to the Java `Context`.

Comment: For the Java `values` object - this appears to be a hashmap containing another hashmap. Is that correct? (Presumably built from a List of component objects). Can you clarify the need to have a nested hashmap (or maybe I am misreading the sample code)?

Comment: The values object is used to send variables to the Thymeleaf context, an approach similar to the one explained here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52736288/how-can-i-pass-object-to-thymeleaf-template-and-access-its-attributes I have edited the post in order to better clarify where cabComb comes from, as you can see it is a variable created when looping through a list with thymeleaf

Comment: Thank you for the updates. That seems to suggest this is not initially a Thymeleaf issue, but a data issue.